# How to edit the default package-info template in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, package, package-info

I just want when i creat new package and i check the **Create package.info.java** check box look like this

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package net.pkg.main.foo;

import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;
```

but right now it just look like this

```
/**
 * @author myname
 *
 */
package net.pkg.main.foo;
```

**My question: is there any way to edit default package-info template in eclipse?**

Thanks in advance <3 <3.